# Numpy Infinity constants - Difference among inf, infty, Inf, Infty. Which one to use when?

Tags: python, numpy

Numpy has several constants providing similar functionality of mathematical inifinity value.
These are - `np.inf`, `np.infty`, `np.Inf`, `np.Infty`.

The docs (https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/constants.html) says that these are all aliases of `np.inf`.

It seems very unpythonic (multiple redundant ways to achieve exact same thing)!
Is there really no difference among them?

Comment: The docs literally tell you which one to use, and why. What's the point of this question?

Comment: In answer to which one to use when, the docs are pretty explicit _"Use inf because Inf, Infinity, PINF and infty are aliases for inf."_ so always use `inf` and never use the other aliases.

Comment: Also, `np.Int` -> `np.inf`

Comment: They're all literally references to the same object. There can't be a difference among them

Comment: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/numeric.py#L2370 they are identical, I don't know why they defined them all though...

Comment: @Dan. "Historical reasons"

Comment: @MadPhysicist - Will the redundant constants get deprecated in coming releases?

Comment: Unlikely, and why does it matter to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the documentation says

> Use [inf](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/constants.html#numpy.inf) because Inf, Infinity, PINF and infty are aliases for inf. For
>   more details, see [inf](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/constants.html#numpy.inf).

You can the check the docs right [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/constants.html#numpy.inf).